# WinAppDriver finds element on one machine but not others

Tags: c#, selenium, winappdriver

I have an automated testing environment consisting of one development machine and two boxes that run the tests in an automated fashion.  All three machines are running windows 10.  All three are using the same verision of the WinAppDriver, and all three are using the latest version of Google Chrome.  All three are running under logged in local admin accounts on the machines.

I initially built all my tests in IE, but due to browser instability have been trying to convert them over to Chrome.

In this particular instance, I am using the WinAppDriver to detect when the browser has presented the download dialogue to the user.  It seems to be working correctly in IE on all the machines.  It is even working correctly in Chrome on the development machine, but it will not work in Chrome on the testing machines.

So far I have been unable to figure out what could be different on the test machines, other than the fact that MSBuild is started by TFS on the test machines and by Visual Studio on the dev machine.

Here is an image of the results returned from the working dev machine.
[image: Working machine]

Here are images of the results from one of the test machines.
[image]

Second image:
[image]

As you can see, other than the flat out failure on the test machines, the only other difference appears to be in the response to the initial browser hook.  The working one does not return a sessionId, while the failing one does.  Which to me indicates a differences in product versions, but I verified the two versions of WinAppDriver were identical.

I have tried multiple versions of the XPath lookup, just in case that was the issue, but all of them work on the dev machine, and none of them have worked on the test machine.

Does anyone have any ideas why my test boxes are unable to perform this lookup specifically in Chrome?

Edit: Code was requested, it's a little redundant with the screenshots, but here it is.

```
this.BaseBrowser.NavigateToUrl(new System.Uri(string.Format("{0}&Export=Excel", MainDocument.PageUrl)));

var wait = new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait(BaseBrowser.Window, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 5000)); // wait for 5 seconds
IWebElement export_cancel = 
        (Settings.TestBrowser == Brow.IE) ? wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//ToolBar/Button[@Name=\"Cancel\"]"))) :
        (Settings.TestBrowser == Brow.Chrome) ? wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//Pane/Pane/Pane/Group/Button[@Name=\"Close\"]"))) :
        null;   // exception thrown on this if statement if browser is Chrome;
Mouse.Click(export_cancel);
```

And the text of the exception, also shown in the screenshots:

> WebDriverException -> An element could not be located on the page
>   using the given search parameters.  StackTrace: at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response
>   errorResponse) at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String
>   driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary'2 parameters) at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism,
>   String value) at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementByXPath(String
>   xpath) at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.b__0(ISearchContext
>   context) at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context) at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by) at
>   SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.b__0(IWebDriver
>   driver) at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait'1.Until[TResult](Func'2
>   condition)

EDIT 2: The BaseBrowser.Window method exerpt that hooks WinAppDriver into the browser process:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] localByName = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(this.BaseProcessName);
foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process item in localByName)
{
    if (item.MainWindowTitle == string.Format(BaseProcessTitleFormat, this.Title))
    {
        DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        desiredCapabilities.SetCapability("appTopLevelWindow", item.MainWindowHandle.ToString("x"));
        RemoteWebDriver session = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(windowsAppDriverUrl), desiredCapabilities, new TimeSpan(0, 1, 30));
        _Window = session;
        break;
    }
}
return _Window;
```

Comment: Post your code (markup of the page you are testing and your selenium code) and/or copy/paste your exceptions.  The screenshots aren't all that helpful.

Comment: This method of downloading is failure prone and time consuming,platform dependent. We faced similar issue and also wanted to migrate the tests to linux machine (headless). The approach we used then was to set a default download location in chrome. Chrome while downloading creates a 'filename.crdownload' file to show the file download is in progress. and finally when file was downloaded completely .crdownload will not be there. So we used to poll this filedownload is complete. And then we used to rename the file with what name we actually wanted for that file.Sorry it is not answer to your ques

Comment: Check "DesiredCapabilities".  It looks like you are using an app capability that may be getting confused with a Selenium driver DesiredCapability.  (namespace issue?)

Comment: @pcalkins please clarify.  If you notice in the screenshots, the correct xpath is getting passed down to the WinAppDriver, which should mean there is no namespace issue involved.  The only options I can think of are: bug inside of WinAppDriver, or WinAppDriver hooking into the wrong process.

Comment: in your 2 test cases you are getting back JSON from Selenium's wire protocol that includes the DesiredCapability of "appTopLevelWindow".

Comment: I'm still a little confused about the code though.  Can you post initialization, imports and previous steps?

Comment: There are thousands of lines of code, I can't post it all.  However, I did add a couple more specific pieces related to the areas you are looking at.  The previous action of consequence in the test method is just a navigation call that initiates the download.  The loop that finds the correct process to hook was also added.

Comment: You are probably on the right path though. I bet that loop is finding the wrong process.  Makes no sense that it only happens on the test machines, but that must be what is happening.

Comment: not familiar with WinAppDriver... but I know there are often namespace issues with webdriver/appwebdriver when using appium.  (check your imports maybe)  Is your "app" actually Chrome in this example?  If you are just automating browsers, it seems like you'd want the normal WebDriver, no?